# MyBB Logo position does not change

Tags: javascript, html, css, mybb

So It's a theme without a responsive logo and
I've been messing around trying to fix it but with any position it doesn't change /:
I wasted days trying to fix this but still it would not work

Does anyone have any suggestions or solutions how to fix this?

Html Code :

```html
<a name="top" id="top"></a> <br /> <br />
<div id="mainwidth"> 

<div id="container">
<div id="content">
    
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li id="nav-portal"><a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/portal.php"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Home</a></li>
<li id="nav-forums"> <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-comments fa-fw"></i> Forums</a></li>
<li id="nav-search"> <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/search.php"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-search fa-fw"></i>  {$lang->toplinks_search}</a></li>
<li id="nav-member"> <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/memberlist.php"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-users fa-fw"></i> Members</a></li>
    <li id="nav-instructions"><img src="img/new-icon.jpg" style="width: 20px;position:center;cursor:pointer;"> <a href="Instructions.php"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-question-circle fa-fw"></i> Forum Instructions</a></li>
<li id="nav-calendar"> <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/calendar.php"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> {$lang->toplinks_calendar}</a></li>
<li id="nav-help"> <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/misc.php?action=help"><i style="font-size: 12px;" class="fa fa-info fa-fw"></i> {$lang->toplinks_help}</a></li>
  <li><a href='javascript:;' id="extraslink"><i style="font-size: 14px;" class="fa fa-angle-down fa-fw"></i>More</a></li>
         <ul>
            </div> 
  <div id="extraslink_popup" class="popup_menu" style="display: none;">
      <div class="popup_item_container">
        <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/member.php?action=logout&amp;logoutkey={$mybb->user['logoutkey']}" class="fa fa-sign-out">  Logout</a>
      </div>
      <div class="popup_item_container">
        <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/showteam.php" class="popup_item">Show team</a>
      </div>
      <div class="popup_item_container">
        <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/search.php?action=getnew" class="popup_item">{$lang->welcome_newposts}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="popup_item_container">
        <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/search.php?action=getdaily" class="popup_item">{$lang->welcome_todaysposts}</a>
      </div>
      <div class="popup_item_container">
        <a href="*" class="popup_item">Link five here</a>
      </div>
  </div>
    
<div class="topbar"> 
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="{$theme['tablespace']}" border="0">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
    
    <!--- LOGOO CODE STARTS HERE    -->
    
    
<div class="logo-b">
    <a href="{$mybb->settings['bburl']}/index.php"><img src="{$theme['logo']}" alt="{$mybb->settings['bbname']}" /></a>
    </div>  
    
    <!--- LOGOO CODE ENDS HERE  -->

</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="bottom">
    
<div style="margin-top: 120px;"><div class="userbg">{$welcomeblock}</div></div>
    
</td>
</tr>
</table>    
</div>
    
             <br />
    
            <div class="wrapper">
                {$pm_notice}
                {$bannedwarning}
                {$bbclosedwarning}
                {$unreadreports}
                {$pending_joinrequests}
                {$awaitingusers}
                <navigation>
                <br />
                    
                    
<script type="text/javascript">
// <!--
    if(use_xmlhttprequest == "1")
    {
        $("#extraslink").popupMenu();
    }
// -->
</script>
```

And the CSS code :

```css
#logo {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 150px;
}
```

I've messed around alot with the CSS code but heres the original one

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't add an element with logo id, add it in html and change it in css. If the problem is still not resolved, check if you have added your css file to html. If the problem still persists, add display: block property to your logo in css and give margin

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Nope doesn't work